# Is the current provided android emulator able to simulate the sensors?

Tags: android

Is the current provided android emulator able to simulate the sensors? If not, can I get a link to third party that will provide me with this? Previous post on stackoverflow and its links are not working

Answer (score 12):

[image]

You do not need a device to simulate Android sensors. The Android Emulator (v25.2.2 and higher), launched with [Android Studio 2.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/09/android-studio-2-2.html) can simulate the following sensor types:

- TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
- TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE
- TYPE_GRAVITY
- TYPE_GYROSCOPE
- TYPE_LIGHT
- TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
- TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD
- TYPE_ORIENTATION
- TYPE_PRESSURE
- TYPE_PROXIMITY
- TYPE_RELATIVE_HUMIDITY
- TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR
- TYPE_TEMPERATURE

As defined here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: Okay. And do I implement SensorEventListener?

Comment: Yes, you should implement SensorEventListener. See the example code here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AccelerometerPlay/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.java#L117

Comment: Could this simulation be performed programmatically?

Comment: How about Z movement?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot emulate sensors from an emulator unless you connect a device:
http://tools.android.com/tips/hardware-emulation

Or you can use 3rd party :
https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator